# fast global search (jsf, spring, hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf

The project, on which i am working,is integrated on spring3, hibernate, jsf2.0, also using annotations.The project have different modules and each module have different processes and each process contains Master Details screens.In module, All Processes are dependent/related to one another from top to bottom.Custom search is developed throughout the module in each process.Now on the project requirements,it needs to develop global search throughout the Module.Each module has 90 database tables with huge data inside and there is a "Item Table" which is used throughout the Module(all processes details screens revised that item). Through global search user will enter an item and search it.Searching should returns all processes details in result(output) within seconds. As i already told above that each table also have huge data inside.What should be the mechanism to develop fast searching feature to avoid from System hanging or going down.

Overview:

```
Searching Flow:Suppose Item No:1234--> Module-->Each process -->Each process details-->items details found
Developing Tools: eclipse-jee-juno-win32 , Microsoft SQL Server.
```

please help

Comment: Consider an external search provider like Solr/ElasticSearch. You should index your content there and make the search provider return and ID which you can use to do a simple query to your RDBMS. Full text search on huge tables cannot perform well.

Comment: this could be an answer :-)

Comment: I agree with previous comment. you should use external search provide to improve performance.  Still wanted to understand some information. Did you say you have same table (Name) "Item table" in all module, each module has different database or do you have one Table for all modules ? . Do you want reuse the search implemented in module ? is it simple search by Item No / complicated with Text Search ? Thing about parallel search and merge results ...

Comment: Agreed with elbuild; although Solr is very high level, perhaps good old Lucene (which Solr is a high level framework around) is already enough.